# OpenShift, Tomcat7 and JDBC Realm

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, openshift, jdbcrealm

I am trying to deploy JaveEE Tomcat7 based application to OpenShift. Whole configuration is based on Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) catridge. Up to now I'd developed my application locally and all worked fine including JDBCRealm based user's authentication.

Project spec, pom.xml attached at the end of the post:

- entirely maven based
- tomcat used via artifact **org.apache.tomcat.maven**

But now I need to make my app available in web, so I decided to go to OpenShift, where I created Tomcat7 application (which is also maven based). Deployment was successful but I am having trouble with JDBCRealm now, which worked locally. The problem is that tomcat fails to find MySQL driver to open realm connection. I'd solved this problem with **org.apache.tomcat.maven** by specifying my context.xml and adding mysql dependency. Howeever **maven-war-plugin** which seems to not have an option to inject the dependency. So i am stucked with an error like this:

```
mar 30, 2013 8:59:08 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm authenticate
SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:702)
    ... 14 more
```

and pom.xml like this, which does not do the job:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>majekwms</groupId>
    <artifactId>majekwms</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>majekwms</name>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>kornicameister</id>
            <email>kornicameister@gmail.com</email>
            <name>Tomasz Trębski</name>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <json-simple.version>1.1.1</json-simple.version>

        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.9</mysql.version>
        <tomcat.maven.version>2.0</tomcat.maven.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.0.CR1</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-annotations.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate-annotations.version>
        <hibernate-common-annotations.version>3.3.0.ga</hibernate-common-annotations.version>
        <gson.version>2.2.2</gson.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.2</slf4j-log4j12.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final-redhat-1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--json-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${json-simple.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--json-->

        <!--hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--hibernate-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps'
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>majekwms</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${tomcat.maven.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>http://127.6.35.1:8080/MajekWMS/</url>
                            <mode>both</mode>
                            <path>/MajekWMS</path>
                            <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
                            <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                            <contextFile>src/main/tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                                <version>${mysql.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                            <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                            <containerConfigXML>src/main/tomcat/context.xml</containerConfigXML>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

And of course my context.xml, which seems to be detected and tomcat tries to read configuration from it, but since mysql driver is missing it fails with SQLException:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context
        className="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext"
        reloadable="true"
        antiJARLocking="true"
        swallowOutput="true">
    <Realm connectionName="user_name_here"
           connectionPassword="pass_here"
           connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/majekwms?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
           roleNameCol="role"
           userCredCol="secPassword"
           userNameCol="login"
           userRoleTable="userRole"
           userTable="user"
           driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           digest="md5"
           className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Make sure that you put the `mysql connector` jar file in tomcat `lib` folder.

Comment: You mean lib folder inside my openshift sandbox ?

Comment: I mean the `lib` folder inside the `tomcat`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting on our forums: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/openshift-tomcat7-and-jdbc-realm#comment-28951

Here's a forum thread that covers this topic: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1040-using-your-own-jar-files-in-a-java-applica...

Can you please take a look at it and see if it helps? Then, if you are still unable to connect, please let us know.

Comment: I'd managed to solve it, before I read your answer. Still thanks for that.Hope that this link will help other:  http://kornicameister.blogspot.com/2013/04/jdbc-realm-tomcat7-and-openshift.html

Answer (score 0):

Giving that in openshift you can deploy only one webapp, you must edit global **context.xml** and **server.xml** to configure a DataSource.

Also you need to add **database jar driver** somewhere where you have write permissions and tomcat can find it.

[here](http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/configuring-jndi-datasource-with-openshift-tomcat-cartridge/) you can show how.